# Web Forms show progress of splitting up large file into smaller ones

Tags: c#, file-upload

I am currently working on a page where a user can upload a large file and enter a amount line numbers. Then my function splits the large file into smaller ones depending of lines numbers the user wants.

Anyway let's say I end up creating 100 files for an original file of 10,000 records and the user wants 100 records per file.

I am looking for a way to display on my screen the number of files created so far while the function is still running ?

```
    protected void SplitFileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(fileName);
        Empty(directory);
        var fileSize = FileSizeInput.Text;
        _sxw.Start();
        SplitFile(100, fileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BackgroundWorker` to do the work.  This will take care of performing the long running work in a non-UI thread, so as to not block the UI, and provides convenient means of updating the UI with the progress of the work as well as updating it when the work is completed.

Simply create a worker, do the work in a `DoWork` event hander, call `UpdateProgress` from that handler when you finish a file, and then update the UI with the current progress in the `ProgressUpdated` event handler.  There are many examples of following this pattern on the MSDN page for `BackgroundWorker`, and elsewhere all around the web.